# C++ Set Array size in constructor, copy a 2D Array

Tags: c++, arrays

So in my header file for a class `Foo` I declare a 2D array of ints like so:

```
int board[][];
```

I am intentionally leaving out a size because I want to set that in the constructor. `board[][]` will not change in size once initialized. One of my constructors looks like this:

```
Foo(int _board[][]);
```

In this I want to set `board[][]` to the same size as `_board[][]` and to also copy the contents. I have tried using this in the .cpp implementation of `Foo`:

```
Foo::Foo(int _board[][]){
board[][] = _board[][]; //Does not work as intended
}
```

However, this does not work as intended. How can I make `board[][]` be the same size and have the same contents as `_board[][]` in the constructor?

Comment: you cant do it using array without knowing the 2nd dimension size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is different than Java. `int a[][];` is not allowed as variable type. Some misleading C++ feature is that first size is allowed to be left empty:

```
int foo(int a[]);
int foo(int a[][3]); 
int foo(int a[][3][4]);
```

Another misleading C++ feature is that this is allowed in initialization of an array (compiler will count the size):

```
int a[][] = {{1,2}, {1,2,3,4}, {1}};
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int a[3][4] = {{1,2}, {1,2,3,4}, {1}};
```

---

For your very case - use std::vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> board;
Foo(std::vector<std::vector<int>> board) : board(board) {}
```

---

If you can't use std::vector for whatever reason - then only solution is to use `int**` with both sizes:

```
int** board;
size_t s1;
size_t s2;
Foo(int** board = NULL, size_t s1 = 0, size_t s2 = 0) : board(board), s1(s1), s2(s2) {}
```

But be aware that you cannot use this way:

```
int board[][] = {{1,1,2},{1,2,2}};
Foo foo((int**)board,2,3);
```

because you must provide a dynamic array:

```
int** board = new int*[2] { new int[3]{1,1,2}, new int[3]{1,2,2}};
```

And since that - you have to implement copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor:

```
Foo(const Foo& other) : TODO { TODO }  
~Foo() { TODO }  
Foo& operator = (Foo other) { TODO }
```

So, just use std::vector.